# Not sure to understand why my server receives "channelInterestChanged" events in the frame decoder

Tags: nio, netty, datagram

I implemented my own frame decoder to parse the bytes received through a UDP socket (using NioDatagramChannelFactory and ConnectionlessBootstrap) according to our protocol.
Just to follow what is happening in the server while receiving messages, I added trace logs in each callback method of the decoder.

It appears that for almost every message the server receives, we can see that the event "channelInterestChanged" is received twice in the method channelInterestChanged(). The value of the event is first 0 (OP_NONE) then 1 (OP_READ).

I read the documentation about this, but I am still not sure to understand why I receive such events. I first through it was because the receive buffer (or the selector queue) was full, but the server receives this event the same number of times it receives the "messageReceived" event (before the decode() method is called) and all the messages/frames are properly decoded as expected. When messages are missing, I do no see any event at all. In this case it is probably because the receive buffer of the datagram socket is full. But even if I increase this receive buffer, I continue to see these events and to miss messages.

So, I am wondering why for each message received, the server also receives two "channelInterestChanged", one with the OP_NONE value and one with the OP_READ value. Please, takes note also that in the channel pipeline, after my frame decoder, there is an ExecutionHandler and another business-specific handler (which sends a JMS message to an ActiveMQ instance).

Any idea or explanation for me?

Thank you.

Comment: Would be interested know it myself. Why don't you try attaching netty source and debugging it, Netty has a `fireEvent` method which sends these events upstream/downstream into the channel. Maybe its coming from the java **NIO selector** itself and Netty is just transmitting it to your frame decoder.

Answer (score 0):

When a DownStreamChannelStateEvent fired from a handler (e.g calling `channel.setReadable()`, `channel.setWriteable()`), the event will change the channel's nio selector key's interested option in the `NioDatagramWorker`, later, a `UpstreamChannelStateEvent` will be fired with changed option (i.e `OP_READ` or `OP_NONE`)

Your frame decoder handler receives `UpstreamChannelStateEvents` because, some other handlers in the pipeline are changing the channel's read interest options (the purpose of calling channel.setReadable/setWriteable is, throttling the read/write to avoid congestion, `OutOfMemoryError` in the application).

If you have any `MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor` in your pipeline (which monitors the size of the channel memory used), it may suspend or resume reading by calling `channel.setReadable()`  any time if the channel receives messages too fast. You may have to configure the MATPE instance with optimum maxChannelMemorySize, maxTotalMemorySize or disable it by setting it to 0.

Comment: Thank you very much for these very clear explications! Yes, I have a MATPE in my pipeline and yes there was a specific value set for the memory size. After I set these parameters to zero,  I effectively noticed that the event stopped to be fired. But until now I was really not sure to understand why exactly, how it was working under the hood!